# expected a run on the drug

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "expected a run on the drug" mean "expected a course on the drug (that is, expected to get treated using the drug)"?

> The New York Times
> @nytimes
> After President Trump received an antibody treatment by Regeneron he called a “cure,” many expected a run on the drug. Instead, many doses are going unused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "run on" a product means many people buying it, so that the available supply is not sufficient to meet the demand.

For example,

> After they announced a successful trial there was a run on the drug company's stock.

> Earlier this year there was a run on toilet paper, leading to empty shelves in the paper products department

Comment: Yes. Lexico says 'a run on' means "A widespread and sudden demand for (a commodity) or a widespread trading in (a currency)"